# Thumbnail is broken when google drive is synced

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm getting the thumbnail of a document using [file.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) API, which is stored the field `thumbnailLink` in the drive response. But after some time, I get only a broken image.

Could you please let me know the exact expiration time of the thumbnail, which determines the expiration time and how to extend it? We can download the thumbnail image, store it in the cloud and then use it. But since the users are many and the documents are many and the thumbnail varies based on the changes, so I don't think this would be a better approach. I wanted to know whether we have any workaround to fix this issue? Do we have anything to play with the google cache? If so, how to do? will this be a permanent solution

Answer (score 0):

[As stated in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/file#uploading_thumbnails)

> Important: Thumbnails are invalidated each time the content of the file changes. When supplying thumbnails, it is important to upload new thumbnails each time the content is modified. Metadata changes do not invalidate thumbnails.

The google drive thumbnail image link changes the file is changed.

You will need to refresh it if the link is bad by doing a [file.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) or upload new thumbnail image metadata whenever you change the file.